# Matlab and making derivative of symbolic function look "nicer"

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am learning about Matlab's ability to do symbolic math and I've come across what I would consider an annoyance that I'm sure is solvable, but I haven't come across the solution yet.

I have defined the following vector

```
function [R1] = R1vec(t)
syms 'x1(t)' 'y1(t)' 'z1(t)'
R1(1,1) = x1;
R1(2,1) = y1;
R1(3,1) = z1;
end
```

and I want to take the derivative and do so by

```
R1dot = diff(R1vec(t))
```

which gives me this output

```
R1dot =

diff(x1(t), t)
diff(y1(t), t)
diff(z1(t), t)
```

is there anyway to make this look nicer? Say maybe `x1'(t)` or `dx1(t)` or anything besides the cumbersome `diff(x1(t),t)`? Can I assign an enumeration or the likes to it so that when it prints on the screen it looks nicer?

Comment: If you want something like this you might try [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/mupad.html), a separate  [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) environment included with the Symbolic Math toolbox (type `mupad` in your Command Window) and whose engine underlies much of the toolbox functionality. Mathematica is another option.

Comment: Yes I prefer Mathematica or Maple however it is for a requirement for an assignment to also use Matlab.  I can easily complete the assignment I just wanted it to look a little nicer.

Comment: so would it suffice to remove all occurrences of "iff(" and ", t)" or do you want something more general?

Comment: because if so an answer could be R1dot=strrep(R1dot,'iff(','') followed by R1dot=strrep(R1dot,', t)',''). You could make a function of that and print its result to screen.